# send a HTTP request using raw socket and WinPcap

Tags: c, http, sockets, winpcap

as part of my project, I'm trying to send IP packets that contain HTTP requests to Google. I'm using Winpcap library and VC++. Currently, I have the TCP three-way handshaing packets done, but I'm stuck on sending the actual HTTP request packet after I send the TCP ACK packet. When I capture the packets using wireshark, this packet is marked "TCP segment of a Reassembled PDU". The protocol column is 'TCP' not 'HTTP' also. What's wrong? How would I send HTTP packets in this way?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't necessarily doing anything wrong.

By default, Wireshark hands the TCP data to a higher level protocol handler - in this case, one that tries to reassemble entire HTTP requests and responses. It attaches the reassembled message to the *final* packet in the sequence, and labels the other packets with "TCP segment of a reassembled PDU":

[image]

You can disable this reassembly feature to examine the individual packets:

- Edit -> Preferences -> Protocols -> TCP
- Uncheck "Allow subdissector to reassemble TCP streams"

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using WinPCap to send the packets?  You should be using normal sockets instead.  Better, use a socket library that implements the HTTP protocol for you, such as curl, or even Microsoft's own WinInet or WinHTTP APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend that you learn the basis of the HTTP protocol before you try this if you're planning on extending this. Mess with doing raw sockets and throwing get requests; read some source code.

However, I wouldn't really see the point of pcap. You should be able to use the Wininet library if you don't want to have to code the actual socket:[Wininet lib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385473%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

However, if you're wanting to code raw sockets, I would go ahead and use winsocks. The difference between HTTP and TCP is hard for some to understand; HTTP is BASED on TCP, so they are technically all in the same, TCP is used for quite literally thousands of applications. Most of the connections on your computer are TCP.

If you're trying to intercept a connection as a MITM attack with a pcap program to send an HTTP request, I would probably learn some programming in Pcap. There are numerous tutorials for this, such as [this one](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html).

PS: Look up a winsocks tutorial as it's quite hard to understand for beginners. Also, winpcap isn't supported on all systems, and it can be (in some cases) a pain to install. It would honestly be better to use winsocks to do this. Wininet has much more support, and I (don't hold me on this) believe that all of the W2K+ builds all have wininet, so for compatability (which I don't really think is a problem for you) issues I would use wininet or winsocks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not finishing the request with `\r\n` twice.

If you send the `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n` string, you will not receive any packets.

You must send this string: `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`.